# Rails - Passing a parameter from one view to a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Fairly simple question, and I've seen lots of similar ones asked in my search, but none of the solutions I've read have worked so far. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

In my application I have Projects and Verifications. When viewing a particular Project, I need to be able to have a link to "Verify Project", which will send the user to a new Verification form. They will enter a variety of values, but I do not want them to have to select the Project that this Verification belongs to by hand -- I want to be able to pass the project_id directly alongside the values the user enters in the Verification form.

On my project view I have:

```
<%= link_to "Verify Project", new_verification_path(:project_id => @project.id ) %>
```

and then in the verifications controller:

```
def new
    @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
    @project = params[:project_id]
end

  def create
    @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
    @verification.project = @project
end
```

but this yields this error:

```
Validation failed: Project does not exist, Project does not exist
```

How can I create my Verification with :project_id being grabbed from the previous page?

EDIT

From the Rails log:
(clicking Verify Project)

> Started GET "/verifications/new?project_id=4" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2013-09-10 04:02:56 +0200 Processing by VerificationsController#new as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"project_id"=>"4"}   Rendered
>   verifications/_form.html.erb (91.3ms)   Rendered
>   verifications/new.html.erb within layouts/application (97.5ms)
>   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)   Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
>   "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."remember_token" =
>   'NuxEYIjeCYyFklN7EyHTDQ' LIMIT 1   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb
>   (38.6ms)   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms) Completed 200 OK
>   in 381ms (Views: 368.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)

and then Create

> Started POST "/verifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-10 04:03:04
>   +0200 Processing by VerificationsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"sqUBXqA6y5oKCW1DFAi3sv8rQzm+tKjOYDdc/lvUS+c=",
>   "verification"=>{"verifier_name"=>"test", "checked_on(1i)"=>"2013",
>   "checked_on(2i)"=>"9", "checked_on(3i)"=>"10", "notes"=>"test"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Verification"}   Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
>   "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."remember_token" =
>   'NuxEYIjeCYyFklN7EyHTDQ' LIMIT 1    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
>   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in
>   18ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Project does not
>   exist, Project does not exist):
>   app/controllers/verifications_controller.rb:55:in `create'

EDIT 2

Here's the form for the Create action:

```
<%= form_for(@verification) do |f| %>
  <% if @verification.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@verification.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this verification from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @verification.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :verifier_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :verifier_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :checked_on %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :checked_on %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :notes %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :notes %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div></div></div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Look in the Rails log to see what the parameters look like when the user clicks your link.  If you post the parameters from the log, the problem will probably be obvious.

Comment: Ok, added to the post

Comment: well you would need to include the project_id in the form you render for the validation.  It is getting to the verfication new, but not getting passed into create.  You can make it as a hidden field, or another option is to just use a nested resource, see my answer to this question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701838/how-can-i-invoke-the-create-method-of-an-object-with-another-objects-id/18702728#18702728   and just substitute project for post and verification for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new` controller action is a bit off. You're assigning an actual `id` to the `@project` instance variable, rather that the `Project` object that corresponds to that `id`. Subsequently, you're passing an invalid `id` from your `new` view to your `create` action.

Fix things by properly assigning the `@project` instance variable in your `new` action:

```
def new
    @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

Then, you'll need to do a proper lookup of the a `Project` object in your `create` action:

```
def create
    @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
    @verification.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @verification.save
end
```

Finally, add the `project_id` as parameter in your form via the `hidden_field` form helper tag:

```
# in your `create` form
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
```

Comment: Just saw the update. Now I get this error: "Couldn't find Project without an ID"

Comment: Please update your question with the form you're using to send to the `create` action.

Comment: You need to add that project id to one of your fields - see my answer for a reference on how to do that.  When you have it right, you will see the project id come through in your params in the log

Comment: I added the project ID in a hidden field, which didn't work until I added @verification.save! to my controller....I knew it was something dumb like that!

Comment: See my update. If this answer helped answer your question, please consider accepting/voting it up. Also, be wary that using `save!` in your controller will necessarily result in an exception being thrown if the save fails. If you want to utilize validations, you'll want to use `save` instead (without the `!`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your project id is passed back to your create method.  You can look up the project as in zeantsol's answer, or you can just pass the project ID.  But you need to make sure that the form you create in your "new" view passes the project id back to your create method (perhaps in a hidden field)

See this post to see an example of using a hidden field in your view:
[Rails hidden field undefined method 'merge' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636875/rails-hidden-field)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried adding the hidden field before, and it had given me the "Couldn't find project without ID" error. Just tried it again, and also added  @verification.save! to the verifications controller, and it suddenly worked.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!